# How can I make my upside-downed stacked graph right using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Chapter 11 of "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web" shows how to create stacked bar charts with the D3.js library. The example produces an upside down chart with the bars attached to the top of the x-axis.

[Upside-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8cNT.png)

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var w = 500;
  var h = 300;

  var dataset = [[ { x: 0, y: 5 }, { x: 1, y: 4 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 7 }, { x: 4, y: 23 }],
    [ { x: 0, y: 10 }, { x: 1, y: 12 }, { x: 2, y: 19 }, { x: 3, y: 23 }, { x: 4, y: 17 } ],
    [ { x: 0, y: 22 }, { x: 1, y: 28 }, { x: 2, y: 32 }, { x: 3, y: 35 }, { x: 4, y: 43 } ]];

  var stack = d3.layout.stack();
  stack(dataset);

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length)).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });
      })])
      .range([0, h]);

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(dataset).enter().append("g")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(i); });

  var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
</script>
```

This is the code that makes stacked bar upside down.

and when I change several codes like following:

1) Change the yScale .range from:

```
.range([0, h]);
```

to

```
.range([h, 0]);
```

2) Change the rect "y" .attr from:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
```

to

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0) + yScale(d.y) - h; })
```

3) Change the rect "height" .attr from:

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
```

to

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d.y); })
```

With those changes applied, the stacks attach to the bottom and still maintain their relative sizes.
[right graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8xUD.png)

The problem is, I don't get the meaning of the second step and the third step.

why should `y` be  `yScale(d.y0) + yScale(d.y) - h`,

and why should `height` be `h - yScale(d.y)`?

If these values are modified to different value(such as `y` be `(yScale(d.y0) + yScale(d.y))/10`  or so), desired graph are not shown.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this "reverse math" (as Scott Murray says in his code) is that in your first code, the upside down one, both the SVG coordinates system and the range have the Y coordinate growing from top to bottom (zero is located at the top and max value at the bottom). But when you reverse the range to `([h, 0])` in the second code, the SVG coordinates system *continues to have Y coordinate growing from top to bottom*, despite the range now going upwards.

In the "upside down" code, the top of the bar is actually its base and its height goes down, together with the SVG system. But in the second code, the "normal" chart, things are more complicated: the "base" of the bar is not its "y" attribute anymore, and the height value adds pixels downwards, regardless the inverted range. The SVG's coordinates system is not automagically inverted just because we inverted the range.

It's complicated, so let me rephrase it: in the SVG coordinates system, the "y" attribute is always the top of the rectangle. In your first code, the top of the rectangle is the base of the bar... but, in your second code, the top of the rectangle is the top of the bar. Confusing, I know.

Let's do a simple math: imagine a SVG with 100 pixels of height and a single bar with 80 pixels of height (y0: 0, y:80). To draw this bar, "y" attribute must set its top. How to calculate it? `yScale(d.y0)` gives us 100, and `yScale(d.y)` gives us 20. By adding them we have 120, which minus 100 (the height) gives us 20, the position of the top. Why not simply using `d.y` straight away? It can work for the first bar, but it won't for the subsequent ones.

Now the height, which must be 80 pixels. `yScale(d.y)` gives us 20, so, 100 (height) minus 20 gives us 80... and this goes for each bar.